# gcc : __sync_lock_test_and_set VS. = operator with volatile variables

Tags: c++, gcc, volatile, built-in

2 threads A and B share a `volatile int i`.

Thread A increments `i` like this : `__sync_fetch_and_add(&i, 1);`

Thread B sets `i` to an arbitrary value V like this : `i = 15;`.

My question: for this kind of usage, should B use `__sync_lock_test_and_set(&i, 15);` instead of direct affectation with `=` operator ?

If yes, does `__sync_lock_release` mandatory just after the test_and_set ?

Env: gcc 4.1.2, centos 5.11 32 bits, no c++11

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use the sync functions then there is data race for `i` between thread A and B.
And as per the definition of `__sync_lock_test_and_set` and `__sync_lock_release`, you should use release after using sync_lock.

[for ref](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.4/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html)